# DataContext in UserControls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding, datacontext

How are `DataContext` in UserControls usually set? If I do something like the below in my UserControl,

```
DataContext = this
```

In my Window or other Controls when I want to use the Control with a Binding, I will have to have a `RelativeSource` to point to the Window/UserControl

```
<local:UserControl1 TextContent="{Binding Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Is the way to bind Controls within UserControls: set use `RelativeSource` in UserControls instead of `DataContext`?

```
<UserControl x:Class="SetCurrentValueTest.UserControl1" ...>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TextContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}}" />
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dunno if it is what you are looking for, but if you want to bind to the UserControls Dependency-Properties, use this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SetCurrentValueTest.UserControl1" ...>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TextContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
</UserControl>
```

And if you want to bind to the UserControl's DataContext, use this Binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SetCurrentValueTest.UserControl1" ...>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.TextContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
</UserControl>
```

Not that I am specifying UserControl as Ancestor-Type and not your Concrete Type (UserControl1).

Comment: The second example won't do anything differently than {Binding TextContent} unless you have set the DataContext to something else between the UserControl and the TextBox; otherwise the TextBlock inherits the DataContext. And specifying UserControl or UserControl1 as the AncestorType will only make a difference if there is another UserControl of a different type contained within the UserControl1 and containing the TextBox.