# Property changed event is not getting fired wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged, prism-6

I have to change the value in a text box dynamically, on selecting a value from a combox box, which is present in different view. when changing the dependency property's source, the propertychangedEventHandler value is not changing, i.e it is remaining as null, so the event is not getting fired. As a result the text in the textbox is not changing. Below is the code. I have bound the text in textbox to _name property.

```
public partial class Details : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   public string name = "";

     public Details()
     {
       InitializeComponent();
       Name = Connector.Name;
       DataContext = this;
     }


    public string Name
    {
       get { return name; }
       set
       {
           name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name");
       }
   }

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string s)
   {
         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null)
         {
             handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
         }
   }
}
```

Xaml code

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <TextBlock Text="Student Details" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">  </TextBlock>

            <StackPanel Margin="0,5" Orientation="Horizontal" >

        <Label MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="110">Name:</Label>

                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2">

                    <TextBox Name="nametextbox" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="auto" MinWidth="100" FontWeight="Black"></TextBox>
                </Border>

            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: What does your binding in XAML look like?

Comment: Does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237443/datacontext-in-usercontrols

Comment: You have a public property named `_name` _and_ a public _field_ named `name`? This is sure violating naming conventions!

Comment: Can you share XAML Code

Comment: How does your provided XAML code is linked to the UserControl class? Can you share the complete XAML file?
How do you change the property? Is it from code? Is it from binding to a different control?
We need more information and the complete source files.

Comment: I am changing the property when an event is fired in a different view. Basically I have two views, one for selecting student name from a list, and the other list showing the details of the selected student(the above xaml is for the same view). The data is being accessed from a Xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you accidentally exchanged `name` and `_name`, using `name` in XAML for the binding?

Usually you have a public property with a capitalized name, and a private field with a non-capitalized name, optionally prefixed with an underscore as you did.

So, you should have

```
public string Name {
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
{

private string _name = "";
```

Please check the following:

- If you're not currently binding to `name` instead of `_name`;
- Either if that is or is not the case, please fix your naming convention, because it is a source of errors, and every example you'll find follow the convention I included above.

Comment: "and a private field with a non-capitalized name prefixed with an underscore", or no underscore at all.

Comment: I have changed the naming convention, still it is not working

Comment: And what about the binding in the XAML? Did you change it there too? The binding property need to have the same name as the public property in your viewmodel.

Comment: Yes I have done that too. Can you tell me how to use Event aggregator in this context. The text should change when the selected item of a combo box changes in another view.

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML, you are binding "Name" property and in your code, you have created _name property. So, you need to change it to "Name" property in your code.

Just change your property as per below:

```
private string _name = "";

public string Name 
        {
    get { return _name; }
    set { 
         _name = value; 
         OnPropertyChanged("Name"); 
        }
}
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: I have done that, but still it is not working. Should I use eventaggregator as this text should change when I select a different item from combo box, in a different view

Answer (score 0):

I have used eventaggregator for this purpose, as we need to change the text in the text box dynamically when an event in a different view is fired. Below is the C# code of both the DropView(where we select student name from a list), and DetailsView(where we display the details). I publish events in Drop.xaml.cs and subscribe to those events in Details.xaml.cs

Drop.xaml.cs

public partial class Drop : UserControl
    {

```
    private IEventAggregator iEventAggregator;

    public Drop(IEventAggregator ieventaggregator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        iEventAggregator = ieventaggregator;
        this.DataContext = this;
        var doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\srinivasaarudra.k\\Desktop\\students.xml");           
        var names = doc.Descendants("Name");
        foreach (var item in names)
        {
            droplist.Items.Add(item.Value);
        }

    }
    public string name;
    public string Naam
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value;
        iEventAggregator.GetEvent<Itemselectedevent>().Publish(Naam);
        }

    }
    public string grade;
    public string Grade
    {
        get { return grade; }
        set
        {
            grade = value;
            iEventAggregator.GetEvent<gradeevent>().Publish(Grade);
        }
    }
    public string dept;
    public string Dept
    {
        get { return dept; }
        set
        {
            dept = value;
            iEventAggregator.GetEvent<deptevent>().Publish(Dept);
        }
    }
    public static string str;
    public static string Str
    {
        get { return str; }
        set {
            str = value;

             }
    }

    private void droplist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var sel = droplist.SelectedValue;
      Str=sel.ToString();
      XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
      doc2.Load("C:\\Users\\srinivasaarudra.k\\Desktop\\students.xml");
      var details = doc2.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Students/StudentDetails");
      foreach (XmlNode node in details)
      {
          if (node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText == Str)
          {
              Naam = node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
              Grade = node.SelectSingleNode("Grade").InnerText;
              Dept = node.SelectSingleNode("Department").InnerText;

          }

      }
    //  Details det = new Details();  
      Details dt = new Details(iEventAggregator);

    }


}
 public class Itemselectedevent:Prism.Events.PubSubEvent<string>
    {

    }
 public class gradeevent : Prism.Events.PubSubEvent<string>
 {

 }
 public class deptevent : Prism.Events.PubSubEvent<string>
 {
 }
```

Details.xaml.cs

public partial class Details : UserControl,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

```
    public IEventAggregator iEventAggregator;

   public  event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public static string name;
   public static string dept;
   public static string grade;

   [Bindable(true)]
   public  string Naam
   {
       get { return name; }
       set
       { 
        name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Naam");
       }

   }
   [Bindable(true)]
   public string Grade
   {
       get { return grade; }
       set
       {

               grade = value; OnPropertyChanged("Grade");

       }
   }
   [Bindable(true)]
   public string Dept
   {
       get { return dept; }
       set
       {

               dept = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Dept");

       }
   }
   public Details(IEventAggregator eventaggregator)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.iEventAggregator = eventaggregator;
       iEventAggregator.GetEvent<Itemselectedevent>().Subscribe((str) => { Naam = str; });
       iEventAggregator.GetEvent<gradeevent>().Subscribe((str) => { Grade = str; });
       iEventAggregator.GetEvent<deptevent>().Subscribe((str) => { Dept = str; });          
       this.DataContext = this;           
   }

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string s)
   {
         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;          
         if (handler != null)
         {
             handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
         }            
   }
   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {  
     Application.Current.Shutdown();
   }      
}
```